# How to find the user with priority in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a user table in laravel app.

I want to find a random user with the lowest number of loan_limit.

Right now I have this.

```
    $random_user = User::inRandomOrder()
            ->where('loan_limit', '<=', 5)
            ->first();
```

But I want to find a random user with the minimum no. Of loan_limit like if a user has a loan_limit of 0, that user will get picked first, and if a user has 1, that user will be selected next, and finally if a user has a limit of 5, then that user will have less probability of getting picked.

Answer (score 2):

you can get all the users with min loan_limit value, then take random one:

```
$random_user = User::whereRaw('loan_limit= (select min(`loan_limit`) from users)')
        ->get()->random();
```